# Enforce Profile Path Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, user-management, user-profile

Is there a way to enforce a profile path in active directory on win server 08 (or set a default one) so that when a user is added the profile path is automatically filled in in the profile tab.

The reason I want to do this is that I am setting up the server and then it's going to be managed by other people. I want to make sure that setting the profile path isn't forgotten because I think it's something that could easily be missed. Also it seems pointless to have to remember to set it each time when it should be the same for each user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. You can, however, configure the profile path via group policies. In that case it is tied to the computer object and not to the user account and thus cannot be forgotten when creating new users.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this but the problem is that I think it applies to local users as well. So every time I logon to the local administrator on a computer it will try and create a roaming profile and mess things up. Let me know if I'm wrong though.

Comment: You are right, the policy applies to local user accounts, too, as documented here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958736.

Comment: I think I might end up doing that. If I set the permissions on the share for domain users only I guess that will mean that local accounts will just get temporary profiles and it shouldn't mess anything up.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Comment: I want to leave it a few more days first to see if anyone else has any info.